# Regular expression exception for text in start and end characters

Tags: php, regex

I was searching regular expression in php but I didn't found it.

I have string: 
`<font size=4>This is size in text</font>`

I need insert any character on start and end of text "size", but only "size" in text. Not on `<font size=4>`.

For example I insert "!"  `<font size=4>This is !size! in text</font>`

Exist some exception for text in start and end characters "<>" ?

I wrote some regular expression
`\>([^>]+)(size)\<`
but this is not working. I get two matches when string is `<font size=4>This is in size</font>`. But it isn't good because "size" can't be at any position

Someone help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: preg_match('/^size\ $/')  I just added a literal space at the end of it.  The way you have it written

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML, use a DOM parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\bsize(?= )
```

Check: https://regex101.com/r/nB1wP4/1

Comment: Of course, but when I need replace character "i" and not a "size"  so "i" will be applicated on text between "<>". And it is for me error

Comment: @LOOK: If i understand you correctly, this `\bsize(?=[^>]+<)` should do then..https://regex101.com/r/nB1wP4/2

Comment: Yes, it's working. Thanks. But when I have string
<font size=4>This is in size</font> 
then size is not matches because there is < it is somehow fix it ?

Comment: @LOOK: In fact you can use `\bsize(?=[^>]*<)` in both of the above cases you mentioned..https://regex101.com/r/nB1wP4/3

Comment: Yes I forgot on * Thanks a lot